# Sql hint to use PK clustered index without knowing it name

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table with two indexes – PK clustered index and non-clustered index. For some reason sql server decided it would be a better idea to use a non-clustered index what results in 30 min execution time (few seconds with clustered index). Is it possible to create a hint that would default to clustered index without knowing it name? I would like to use it as temp solution to give some more time for investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table hints!

FROM MSDN:

> If a clustered index exists, INDEX(0) forces a clustered index scan
>   and INDEX(1) forces a clustered index scan or seek.